# python tkinter read only entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am computer science first year student and only learnt python for 2 months. I am currently working on my assignment which requires me to create a tkinter GUI.
I have used:

```
from tkinter import*
def conselect(evt):
    value=str((lstName.get(lstName.curselection())))
    infile=open("list.txt",'r')
    for line in infile:
        data=line.split(',')
        if line.startswith(value):
            print(data[1])
    infile.close()
window=Tk()
window.title("Countries")
lstName=Listbox(window,width=100,height=100)
yscroll=Scrollbar(command=lstName.yview)
yscroll.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=NS,rowspan=3)
lstName=Listbox(window,width=15,height=10,yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
lstName.grid(row=0,padx=0,pady=0,sticky=W,columnspan=2,rowspan=3)
yscroll.config(command=lstName.yview)
continent=[]
lstName.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',conselect)

infile=open("list.txt",'r')
for line in infile:
    data=line.split(',')
    countryName=data[0]
    lstName.insert('end',countryName)
infile.close()
labelC=Label(window,text="Continent :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
labelC=Label(window,text="Population :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=1,column=4,sticky=W)
labelC=Label(window,text="Area :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=2,column=4,sticky=W)

entOutput=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=0,column=5)
entOutput=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=1,column=5)
entOutput=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=2,column=5)
```

How do i print my conselect(evt) output to entry widget at the end of code

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow. I am a little confused. Are you trying to replace the string in the `entry` widget with the result from `data(1)` or are you trying to print the result to a text box widget?

Comment: I am trying to print the result to an entry widget...

Comment: I provided an answer that print the string to either entry or a text box. Take a look at my answer Nd let me k ow if it helped.

Comment: I am trying to have one Listbox and another entry widget on my GUI 
so that when user click something on the Listbox the entry widget will print out a another data.
For example when I click A on Listbox the entry widget shall print 1.

Comment: In my text file its like
A,1
B,2
C,3 etc. so i am not sure how to turn data[1] to String so i can input with your method

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

after reading your updated question I have looked over the code and made some changes. I will break it down in the following code.

Because you did not provide a testable example of your text file I had to create my own with what I thought would be the kind of information you are using.

The file is read by `json` and is a list of list. Below is the content of that file:

```
[
["test 1", "Neverland", "9,000,000", "1000 SQ Miles"],
["test 2", "Ashgard", "1,000,000", "100 SQ Miles"],
["test 3", "Bacon Nation", "3,000,000", "400 SQ Miles"],
["test 4", "Lolzville", "22,000,000", "10000 SQ Miles"]
]
```

I have added a new import `json`. This will be needed for some other changes I made.

```
from tkinter import *
import json

window=Tk()
window.title("Countries")

lstName=Listbox(window,width=100,height=100)
yscroll=Scrollbar(command=lstName.yview)
yscroll.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=NS,rowspan=3)
lstName=Listbox(window,width=15,height=10,yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
lstName.grid(row=0,padx=0,pady=0,sticky=W,columnspan=2,rowspan=3)
yscroll.config(command=lstName.yview)

labelC=Label(window,text="Continent :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
labelC=Label(window,text="Population :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=1,column=4,sticky=W)
labelC=Label(window,text="Area :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=2,column=4,sticky=W)
```

Here I had to change the Entry widget names so I was able to target each of them for later configurations.

```
entOutput=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=0,column=5)
entOutput2=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput2.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=1,column=5)
entOutput3=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput3.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=2,column=5)
```

I change the way we ope the file to use `with open` this will handle file close for us. Also we can perform all the stuff we need to in a manner similar to a function inside the `with open` statement. What we did here was load the content of the list.text file into the global namespace as a variable called `loaded_list`. This will be used for the rest of the program.

```
with open("list.txt",'r') as l:
    loaded_list = json.load(l)
    for line in loaded_list:
        countryName=line[0]
        lstName.insert('end',countryName)
```

Here we get the first value in the tuple that is returned from `curselection` and use it to identify the index of the correct list inside of the `loaded_list` variable we created earlier. The for each of the entry fields we had to change their state to normal, make the updates to the entry field, then change the state back to 'readonly'. By doing it this way all 3 fields can be updated with the pre-defined index of the corresponding fields.

```
def conselect(evt):
    value = lstName.curselection()[0]
    templist = loaded_list[value]

    entOutput.config(state = NORMAL)
    entOutput.delete(0, END)
    entOutput.insert(0, templist[1])
    entOutput.config(state = "readonly")

    entOutput2.config(state = NORMAL)
    entOutput2.delete(0, END)
    entOutput2.insert(0, templist[2])
    entOutput2.config(state = "readonly")

    entOutput3.config(state = NORMAL)
    entOutput3.delete(0, END)
    entOutput3.insert(0, templist[3])
    entOutput3.config(state = "readonly")

lstName.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',conselect)


window.mainloop()
```

Here is an image of how it would work:

[image]

Here is the full code for you to copy:

```
from tkinter import *
import json

window=Tk()
window.title("Countries")

lstName=Listbox(window,width=100,height=100)
yscroll=Scrollbar(command=lstName.yview)
yscroll.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=NS,rowspan=3)
lstName=Listbox(window,width=15,height=10,yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
lstName.grid(row=0,padx=0,pady=0,sticky=W,columnspan=2,rowspan=3)
yscroll.config(command=lstName.yview)

labelC=Label(window,text="Continent :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
labelC=Label(window,text="Population :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=1,column=4,sticky=W)
labelC=Label(window,text="Area :")
labelC.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=2,column=4,sticky=W)

entOutput=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=0,column=5)
entOutput2=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput2.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=1,column=5)
entOutput3=Entry(window,width=10,state="readonly")
entOutput3.grid(padx=5,pady=0,row=2,column=5)

with open("list.txt",'r') as l:
    loaded_list = json.load(l)
    for line in loaded_list:
        countryName=line[0]
        lstName.insert('end',countryName)

def conselect(evt):
    value = lstName.curselection()[0]
    templist = loaded_list[value]

    entOutput.config(state = NORMAL)
    entOutput.delete(0, END)
    entOutput.insert(0, templist[1])
    entOutput.config(state = "readonly")

    entOutput2.config(state = NORMAL)
    entOutput2.delete(0, END)
    entOutput2.insert(0, templist[2])
    entOutput2.config(state = "readonly")

    entOutput3.config(state = NORMAL)
    entOutput3.delete(

0, END)
    entOutput3.insert(0, templist[3])
    entOutput3.config(state = "readonly")

lstName.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',conselect)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply
How about selection on a Listbox widget instead of button?
I am trying to have one Listbox and another entry widget on my GUI 
so that when user click something on the Listbox the entry widget will print out a another data.
For example when I click A on Listbox the entry widget shall print 1.

Comment: @Bee Jian Sheng: It is very possible to use a list box however that is a different question than the one you have asked. Lets get this question done and solved before we move on to a new question. Also In order for me to solve your problems you have mentioned in the comments I need to see more of your code.

Comment: @Bee Jian Sheng: Ok I changed my answer to reflect your updated question. Let me know if it helps. Note I had to create my own text file with fields I thought you would be using because you did not provide a complete example of your text file. However I believe this should be a good answer for you.

Comment: Thanks! Sierra Mountain Tech. 'json' is a new function for me. I will search online for its tutorial. Thank you so much for helping. It definitely helps a lot. I have stuck in this part for weeks. =)

Comment: @Bee Jian Sheng: You will find many helpful libraries out there for python. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

To make your textbox read only you can try to configure the textbox element using

```
text.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: The OPs question is how to make a response shown in the widget not how to disable the widget.

Comment: I am trying to print the result to an entry widget...
I am trying to have one Listbox and another entry widget on my GUI 
so that when user click something on the Listbox the entry widget will print out a another data.
For example when I click A on Listbox the entry widget shall print 1.

Comment: Thanks anyway mate